# My website's image does not work with twitter cards (unclear issues with robots.txt)

Tags: html, robots.txt, meta-tags, twitter

## Problem

I am trying to properly **set up metadata for a twitter summary card** on my website. I have everything in place, but **the card image is not showing**.

I use Grav, but I guess it does not matter.

## Setup

This is what I get when using https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator on my website (https://replayer.app/)

```
INFO:  Page fetched successfully
INFO:  18 metatags were found
INFO:  twitter:card = summary tag found
INFO:  Card loaded successfully
WARN:  The image URL https://replayer.app/user/pages/01.home/web-app-on-phone-stand.png specified by the 'twitter:image' metatag may be restricted by the site's robots.txt file, which will prevent Twitter from fetching it.
WARN:  this card is redirected to https://replayer.app/en
```

The image is available at the given URL, I checked with a browser. The robots.txt is what I got from the initial install by Grav:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /backup/
Disallow: /bin/
Disallow: /cache/
Disallow: /grav/
Disallow: /logs/
Disallow: /system/
Disallow: /vendor/
Disallow: /user/
Allow: /user/pages/
Allow: /user/themes/
Allow: /user/images/
Allow: /
Allow: *.css$
Allow: *.js$
Allow: /system/*.js$
```

Since the image is in `/user/pages/`, and it's allowed I would expect no issues.

## Question

**Why does the twitter card validator complain, and the image is not showing on tweets, when the image is available, and not excluded by anything?**

## Notes

For reference, here's the output of the validator:

[image]

Note: I looked into

- [Twitter card [summary_large_image] not displaying image](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77527/twitter-card-summary-large-image-not-displaying-image), but they get no WARN message at all
- [Twitter cards not showing when I tweet](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/123738/twitter-cards-not-showing-when-i-tweet), but I explicitly talk about my setup, not the tweet itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per https://www.robotstxt.org/norobots-rfc.txt :

> To evaluate if access to a URL is allowed, a robot must attempt to
> match the paths in Allow and Disallow lines against the URL, in the
> order they occur in the record. The first match found is used. If no
> match is found, the default assumption is that the URL is allowed.

You have:

```
User-agent: *

...

Disallow: /user/
Allow: /user/pages/
Allow: /user/themes/
Allow: /user/images/
```

So everything under `/user/` is disallowed as this is the first match, including hence `/user/images`.

You may need to change the order of the directives.

Comment: I have done so, and it now works. PLUS, for the actual image to display it has to be strictly square, in my experience.